# TAblerates upload: something went wrong with importing tablerates

Tags: magento2, import, table, table-rates

When importing the tablerates i get the message:

> something went wrong

when importing the tablerates.

I can't find the reason why, could you give me a hint? On the internet i could not find anything. Configuration is on mainwebsite, price vs destination.

Comment: Whats your Magento version ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Exported .CSV File in **Text Editor** (Notepad, Notepad++, Sublime).
2. Then you will see 
   **Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"** , then put the details. Ex. **PHL, Region10, 8703, 1.0000, 10.0000**.

[image]

3. Then Import the File.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was a problem with the `.csv` column headers. Magento 2 doesn't use the `Delivery Type` column used in Magento 1. Just export the current .csv and make sure they match.

Answer (score 0):

For magento version 2.3.4 do the following:

1. Make sure your file is based on the correct "Condition" attribute:

   ```
   a) Weight v. Destination
   b) Price v. Destination
   c) Number of Items v. Destination
   ```
2. Remove the quotation mark(") from all the header columns:

   ```
   Ex(Weight v. Destination):
   WRONG->Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Weight (and above)","Shipping Price"
   CORRECT->Country,Region/State,Zip/Postal Code,Weight (and above),Shipping Price
   ```

That will do it.